# url.request.urlritrive is not downloading the images

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, download, urllib

```html
<body><img src="https://www.tkrcetautonomous.org/StudentLogin/Student/StudentPhoto.aspx?StudId=1447&amp;ColCode=PSS" alt="https://www.tkrcetautonomous.org/StudentLogin/Student/StudentPhoto.aspx?StudId=1447&amp;ColCode=PSS"></body>
```

I had already searched for the answer but I didn't get what I want. 
I'm trying to download the images from our college portal which needs to be logged for getting any thing accessed, that is it has a cookie system and not like other pages url at least. It doesn't have any image extensions like **.png,.jpg,...etc.** 
it has a similar link like this *https://www.tkrcetautonomous.org/StudentLogin/Student/StudentPhoto.aspx?StudId=1102&ColCode=PSS*

## Its downloading a broken image ..

I have tried many solutions from **stack overflow** but none worked for my requirement but one. When I inspect the url element there I got an option called copy data url. It's very long and when I use that link in url retrive its working fine.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.find_element_by_id('lnkLogins').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkStudent"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('txtUserId').send_keys(st)
driver.find_element_by_id('txtPwd').send_keys(st)
driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')

table = soup.find('img',{'id':'ImgStudent'}).get('src')
s= 'https://www.tkrcetautonomous.org/StudentLogin/Student/'+table
print(s)
driver.get(s)
k = urllib.request.urlretrieve(s,filename=os.path.basename(st)+'.png')
```

I want to get an image downloaded like when we save image using right click but I'm getting a broken image.

Comment: Can we see some of the offending HTML? Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html.

Comment: could you print out the contents of `table` :)

Comment: Yes I can print @David

Comment: I didn't get u @QHarr

Comment: sorry @ManeeshChinnu i meant could you show us the content of table just before it gets appended to the URL :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply ,, the content will be like StudentPhoto.aspx?StudId=1447&ColCode=PSS   
it will be varying for different users